# Hibernate manually delete a specific Many-Many association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

So I have two classes : `File` and `FileSet`, which have a bidirectional many-many relationship linked by a join table `FILE_FILE_SET`.

One File can be part of many FileSets, and vice versa. Alterations to FileSets are cascaded to individual files through the `@ManytoMany(cascade = CascadeType.All)` annotation (but not the other way round). In particular, it is not uncommon to encounter >1000 files in a FileSet. We have the code for these classes up and running, but we have a problem when we try to delete individual Files from FileSets: while the deletion occurs correctly, as the number of files in the set increases, the time taken for deletion scales with O(n^2). This is because the current code for deleting the FileSet-File association gets an instance of the FileSet, removes the File and then saves the updated FileSet with `SaveOrUpdate()`, which in turn saves all the associated Files.

This is fine for small sets, but gets restrictively slow when there are many Files in a FileSet. Unfortunately, FileSet objects are saved at a number of other points in the code where cascading is a good thing, so I'd rather not turn off cascading altogether.

So, to reach my actual question: is there a way in hibernate to remove a specific association between two objects? For example, is there an HQL query I could run to remove the entry from the join table?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, CascadeType.ALL on a ManyToXxx association doesn't make much sense. If the files of a fileset are part of another fileset, you don't want to delete all the files when you delete a fileset, since they're still referenced by other filesets.

Now, to answer the question, what you want it to remove files from a fileset. This is simply done by removing the files from the collection of files in the fileset:

```
public removeFilesFromFileSet(FileSet fileSet, Set<File> filesToRemove) {
    fileSet.getFiles().removeAll(filesToRemove);
}
```

This loads all the files in the FileSet, though. If you don't want that, then you'll have to either map the association table, or use SQL.

Comment: Well, it's not my code originally: I'm not sure why it isn't many-to-one though. The current code does remove the file in the way you describe: the problem is that this also re-saves all the other files in the FileSet.

Comment: It shouldn't. You say that you call saveOrUpdate() in your question. Note that my answer doesn't. So it shouldn't cascade anything. And I guess you mean OneToMany.

Comment: No luck, I'm afraid: if the save operation is removed, then the entry remains in the join table.

Comment: Is the FileSet the owner of the association, or does it have a meppedBy attribute in its ManyToMany annotation? Either it's not the owner of the association, or you're working on deteched entities instead of working on attached entities.

Comment: The FileSet is definitely the owner of the association. We could well be working with detached entities: the save operation is performed by `getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(FileSet)`. Any suggestions?